# Facebook APP is not available in the iOS Facebook-APP

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-apps

Excuse me for the confusing title. We have programmed App which runs with in the Facebook. It can be accessed over the desktop/notebook browsers. However it is not accessible/available if I login to the Facebook app on my iPhone and go to the APP list. Following scenarios does not work. 
1) If somebody sends me the invitation to use the APP using Facebook message.  If I now login to the Facebook-app on my iPhone and go to the messages and click on the invitation, I see the error. "Page not found". This works perfectly if I login to Facebook using browser (on laptop or iPhone)
2) On my iPhone, in the Facebook APP, if go to list of my APPs then our APP is not available in that list. (Other apps like candy crush and so on can be found)

Are we missing some configuration?

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are talking about a canvas app?

Those are not available on mobile, and never have been. But you can specify a Mobile Site URL in your canvas settings – users on mobile devices, that follow a link to your canvas app somewhere will then automatically be redirected to that external address.

Little cave-at: This has been disabled on a larger scale by Facebook recently, because some people where using it to redirect users to malware sites. Therefor now you have to get your app “white-listed” before this will work. Check this bug report, the FB engineer mentions are form where you can request this: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1051463851558493/

Comment: Thanks. We will test this today and come back with feedback.

Comment: Hi, your have news?

Comment: Thanks CBore it seems this was the problem. No news yet. It's been almost one month but no answer from Facebook nor any status update about the whitelisting request.